# Doctrine2 select distinct with orderby (case when)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am having some trouble with doctrine2. I want to order a query but by day of the week.

What do I mean:

If where the day of the date given is `Tuesday`, I want to have it ordered by `Tuesday, Wednseday, ..., Sunday, Monday`.

But an performance can have multiple days.

The code I got here does the trick for the order by

```
public function getValidPerformancesByDay2($date, $max = 25, $from, $asSql = false){

    $myday = intVal(date('w',strtotime($date)));
    $q = $this->getEntityManager()
             ->createQueryBuilder()
             ->select('DISTINCT textdesc, 
              CASE WHEN (perfdays.id < '. $myday .') THEN perfdays.id + 8 
                   ELSE perfdays.id END AS HIDDEN sortvalue')
             ->from ('sys4winsegundaBundle:Performance','textdesc')
             ->join('textdesc.days', 'perfdays')
             ->where ('textdesc.enddate >= :date')
             ->andWhere('textdesc.isvalid = true')
             ->orderBy('sortvalue','ASC')
             ->setMaxResults($max)
             ->setFirstResult($from)
             ->setParameter('date',$date)
             ;

    $query = $q->getQuery();                   
    if ($asSql){
        return $query;
    }

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

But unfortunately, when I look at the query that has been sent it is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p0_.id AS id0, p0_.name AS name1, p0_.duration AS duration2,
 p0_.addedby AS addedby3, p0_.startdate AS startdate4, p0_.enddate AS enddate5,
 p0_.starthour AS starthour6, p0_.flyer AS flyer7, p0_.price AS price8,
 p0_.discount AS discount9, p0_.isvalid AS isvalid10, 
 p0_.archivedon AS archivedon11, p0_.description AS description12,
 p0_.weblink AS weblink13, p0_.techinfo AS techinfo14, p0_.slug AS slug15,
 CASE WHEN (d1_.id < 4) THEN d1_.id + 8 ELSE d1_.id END AS sclr16,
 p0_.place_id AS place_id17, p0_.gallery_id AS gallery_id18 FROM performances
 p0_ INNER JOIN performance_day p2_ ON p0_.id = p2_.performance_id
 INNER JOIN days d1_ ON d1_.id = p2_.day_id WHERE p0_.enddate >= ? AND
 p0_.isvalid = 1 ORDER BY sclr16 ASC OFFSET 0
Parameters: ['2012-08-23']
Time: 5.13 ms
```

Which means that if a performance occurred 3 times a week, I get 3 occurrences.

anyone got an idea?

---

**EDIT**
 my english being pretty bad, i lltry to explain it differently:
Well i got art performances that occurs on various days.

What i want to do is order them by nearest occurence in time. 
But  the way i sent it to database is with a startdate, an enddate and then what days it occurs (Tuesday, wednesday...)

My query does this( ordering by nearest one) but as some performance occured for example on wednesdays y fridays, my query will return that performance 2 times (on for wednsday and the other one for friday) while i should only retrieve on occurance of each performance but with the same order (nearest first)

Answer (score 0):

If you want 1 occurrence per week use

```
$q->groupBy()
```

For the date converted to week number. And use count() in your select. I'm not sure that I Understand your question.